# FTP server Image blocked in html page in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ftp

I have set up an FTP server and kept few images on the same.

When I request to the ftp server from browser the image is shown.

But I want to show the same images by using HTML tag generated like `<img class="e-thumbImage" unselectable="on" src="ftp://172.16.104.121/filebrowser/3.png?1531887446850">` from ftp://172.16.104.121/FileBrowser/ server in local my machine.

But the image is not loading. The network request shows that **(blocked:origin)**.

I have tried to set below CORS origin in **Web.config** file on MVC project `<system.webServer>`. But it's not working properly.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I didn't find any relevant content on the internet regarding the same issue.

I want to display the image in the browser. Am I going in right direction? Can anyone help me for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
src="ftp://172.16.104.121/filebrowser/3.png"
```

Instead of

```
src="ftp://172.16.104.121/filebrowser/3.png?1531887446850"
```